# Is there a difference between using object literals vs function expressions with Object.create?

Tags: javascript, object

When using Object.create, does it make a difference whether the prototype is an object literal or a function expression?

In this example, does it matter whether the prototype is defined as a function or an object?

```
var CircleObj = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

var CircleFunc = function(){
  this.x = 0; 
  this.y = 0;
}

var myCircleObj = Object.create(CircleObj, {
  x: { writable: true, configurable:true, value: 1 },
  y: { writable: true, configurable:true, value: 1 }
});

var myCircleFunc = Object.create(CircleFunc, {
  x: { writable: true, configurable:true, value: 2 },
  y: { writable: true, configurable:true, value: 2 }
});
```

EDIT

I was confusing the question by overriding the properties at the get-go. 
Using Object.create without properties makes it obvious that it only works with objects.

```
var myCircleObj = Object.create(CircleObj) 
var myCircleFunc = Object.create(CircleFunc)
```

Comment: The second example is not valid. As is, using null instead of the function :  myCircleFunc=Object.create(null, {x:..., y:...} would create an object with same functionalities. Check Object.create's definition on MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.create 1st argument means new Object will inherit those properties. In your example:

Case 1:
New object will inherit x & y property from CircleObj

Case 2:
New object won't inherit x & y property from CircleFunc, because it is meant to be called as function with or without new.

But since you're overriding x & y properties in your Object.create in case 1 & 2. You're not using them properly.

**So pass an Object literal or new Object() to Object.create's 1st argument in order to inherit it's properties from it.**